# dynamically populate VoiceCommand PhraseList, Error VoiceCommandSet not found

Tags: cortana, phrases, vcd

I am looking for a way to dynamically populate my VCD file. I have a Code snippet from the Windows documentation that reads as follows:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.VoiceCommands.VoiceCommandDefinition.VoiceCommandSet commandSetEnUs;

if (Windows.ApplicationModel.VoiceCommands.VoiceCommandDefinitionManager.
      InstalledCommandSets.TryGetValue(
        "AdventureWorksCommandSet_en-us", out commandSetEnUs))
{
  await commandSetEnUs.SetPhraseListAsync(
    "destination", new string[] {“London”, “Dallas”, “New York”, “Phoenix”});
}
```

But, when I put this into my version of App.OnActivated() Visual Studio shows an error saying that VoiceCommandSet is not contained in "Windows.ApplicationModel.VoiceCommands.VoiceCommandDefinition". My questions are:

Am I doing that in the wrong place? Do you know any example projects, that show how to do this properly? (I looked into Adventure Works, but didn't find these lines over there) Or am I missing some references, that I'm not aware of?

Comment: In the meantime I found out that AdventureWorks is doing this in TripViewModel.UpdateDestinationPhraseList

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task UpdateDestinationPhraseList()
        {
            try
            {
                // Update the destination phrase list, so that Cortana voice commands can use destinations added by users.
                // When saving a trip, the UI navigates automatically back to this page, so the phrase list will be
                // updated automatically.
                VoiceCommandDefinition commandDefinitions;

                string countryCode = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name.ToLower();
                if(countryCode.Length == 0)
                {
                    countryCode = "en-us";
                }

                if (VoiceCommandDefinitionManager.InstalledCommandDefinitions.TryGetValue("AdventureWorksCommandSet_" + countryCode, out commandDefinitions))
                {
                    List<string> destinations = new List<string>();
                    foreach (Model.Trip t in store.Trips)
                    {
                        destinations.Add(t.Destination);
                    }

                    await commandDefinitions.SetPhraseListAsync("destination", destinations);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Updating Phrase list for VCDs: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```